# Automated database restore from *.sql files

Tags: python, mysql, database, repository, backup

I am trying to write a python script with which to restore our database. We store all our tables (individually) in the repository. Since typing "source table1.sql, source table2.sql,.." Will be cumbersome I've written a script to do this automatically.

I've found a solution using Popen.

`process = Popen('mysql %s -u%s -p%s' % (db, "root", ""), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.communicate('source' + file)[0]`

The method appears to work very well, however, for each table, it prompts me for a password. How do I bypass this to either get it prompt for a password only once or have the subprocess read the password from a config file?

Is there a better way to do this? I've tried to do this using a windows batch script, but as you'll expect, this is a lot less flexible than using python (for e.g)

Comment: -p%s with an empty password makes it prompt..

Comment: That fixed it! Now how do I vote you as best answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since apparently you have an empty password, remove the -p option, -p without a password makes mysql prompt

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen('mysql %s -u%s' % (db, "root"), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.communicate('source' + file)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent exposing the password to anyone with permission to see running processes, it's best to put the password in a config file, and call that from the command-line:

The config file:

```
[client]
host=host_name
user=user_name
password=your_pass
```

Then the command-line:

> mysql --defaults-extra-file=your_configfilename

Comment: Thanks. This suggestion was helpful as well.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could pass it on in the command line after reading it from a file

```
with open('secret_password.txt', 'r') as f:
    password = f.read()
process = Popen('mysql %s -u%s -p%s' % (db, "root", password), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE,
```

Otherwise you could investigate pexpect, which lets you interact with processes. Other alternatives for reading from a config file (like ConfigParser) or simply making it a python module and importing the password as a variable.

Comment: You don't need anything as complex as a parser or pexpect. Just tell the mysql client to use a config file - it can do that itself.